# Check is textarea empty (treating only 'enter' like empty)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Welcome,

I have textarea and i have small function what allow me to submit message on enter keypress.

```
$(function(){
    $('input').keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {

          $(".sender").click();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

That's work fine, i mean great :)

Next, i want disallow sending empty form.
So i was thinking it will be a easy task.

```
var tag = $("#mytextarea").val();

if(tag.length<1 )
{
//empty
}
else
{
//not empty
}
```

But it's not working. I also try val=='' 
I think it count that enter what user hit to send form ;)
I was trying alert value, but i got only that enter...

So, how can i check if is empty or not, but counting enter, like empty.
If only enter will be found, threat like empty space val==''

Regards

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
/\S/.test(tag);
```

`\S` is regex for "any non-whitespace character".

So if that pattern matches `tag`, that means `tag` contains any non-whitespace character.

```
if(/\S/.test(tag)) {
   // has content!
}
```

**Update** Looking at this question 12 years later, we now have `.trim()` support in all browsers, and the code would more clearly express your intent if you were to say something like:

```
if (tag.trim().length > 0) {
   // has content!
}
```

Comment: add the carrot symbol start with an empty space
```js     
 /^\S/  ```

Comment: ``` /^\S/ ``` how does one add code in the comment section???

Comment: @denOldTimer: That would only check that the code *starts* with a non-empty character, which doesn't appear to be what OP is interested in. Anyway, now that we have `trim()`, that seems like the more reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regexp for this, also includes cases when you have a carriage return:

```
if(tag.search(/[^\n\s]/)!=-1)
{
//not empty
}
else
{
//empty
}
```